# Will my anaconda installation be lost if I stop and restart my ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, anaconda, amazon-efs

I spent a lot of time installing all the necessary packages in anaconda and fastai on my p2.xlarge. When I try to stop my ec2 instance, it says all files on my ephemeral storage will be lost. Does this mean I will have to reinstall all the packages if I stop (not terminate) and restart the machine?

I have an efs attached to my machine. Is there a way I can save an image of the current state and reload it when I restart the ec2 instance?

Comment: p2 doesn't have any instance store/ephemeral storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation will be lost if you terminate the instance.
Stopping your ec2 instance will not delete anything, but stopping the instance(instead of terminating it) will charge your account.

Comment: Thank you. I stopped and started my instance and everything was intact.